# Nginx GET параметры и rewrite

Tags: nginx

Здравствуйте.

Второй день бьюсь, не могу сообразить.

Нужно было c:

```
http://site.ru/index.php?code=230&status=ok
```

Средиректить на:

```
http://site.ru/logger/code-230/status/ok
```

С горем(гуглом) по полам пришел к такому решению:

```
if ( $args ~ code=(\d+)&status=(\w+) ) {
    set $code $1;
    set $status $2;
    set $args '';
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /logger/code-$code/status/$status permanent;
}
```

Все работает, но сегодня потребовалось добавить параметров:

```
http://site.ru/index.php?code=230&status=ok&custom1=233524543&custom2=6785457
```

Прошлое правило не работает.
Можно добавить все остальные поля в ручную, но их порядок может измениться, или кол-во.

Вопрос:
Можно как то по первым (code и status) строить чпу, а остальное оставить в GET ?

И еще, было бы шикарно, что бы порядок code и status был не важен, но это, наварное, на грани фантастики...

Спасибо.

Comment: Вообше-то есть переменные `$arg_code`, `$arg_status` и т.п. (`$arg_...`). Но по хорошему проще этот редирект нужно делать не в nginx, а в `index.php`

Comment: @Alexey Ten, в итоге так и сделал...